# Yup validation based on value of another select field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have two select inputs `pickUpTime` and `dropOffTime` in react-hook-form populated with an array of strings. The array `intervalTime` is an ordered time slots with a 15 minutes interval

```
const IntervalTime = [
    '09:00',
    '09:15',
    '09:30',
     ...
]
```

I want to add an error if `dropOffTime` is before `pickUpTime` and I thought of comparing the indexes of the selected time slots to do so

```
 resolver: yupResolver(yup.object({
            pickUpTime: yup.string().required(t('required')),
            dropOffTime: yup.string().when(['pickUpTime', 'dropOffTime'], {
                is: (pickUpTime, dropOffTime) =>
                    IntervalTime.indexOf(dropOffTime) < IntervalTime.indexOf(pickUpTime),
                then: yup.string().required('Drop off time must be after pick up time'),
            }),
        }))
```

but I get `Error: Cyclic dependency, node was:"dropOffTime"`

Comment: You do not have to pass `dropOffTime` to `when()` and, for example, you could get it from `schema` (2nd parameter the callback) using `transform()`. See for example https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemawhenkeys-string--string-builder-object--values-any-schema--schema-schema

Comment: Can you maybe write an example on how you would cast the value of `dropOffTime` using `transform()`. I can't get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
resolver: yupResolver(yup.object({
            pickUpDate: yup.date().required(t('required')),
            pickUpTime: yup.string().required(t('required')),
            dropOffDate: yup.date().min(yup.ref('pickUpDate'), t('date-before')).required(t('required')),
            dropOffTime: yup.string().test('time', 'Drop off time must be after pick up time', function (value) {
                const { pickUpTime, pickUpDate, dropOffDate } = this.parent;
                if (!pickUpTime || !pickUpDate || !dropOffDate || !value) return true; // skip validation if any field is empty
                return (dropOffDate > pickUpDate) || (dayjs(dropOffDate).date() === dayjs(pickUpDate).date() && dayjs(dropOffDate).month() === dayjs(pickUpDate).month() && IntervalTime.indexOf(value) >= IntervalTime.indexOf(pickUpTime));
            }).required(t('required')),
        }))
```

I added a bit of validation to check if dropOffDate is after pickUpDate. In that case there's no need to check time as well.

Answer (score 1):

just use `.test()` and write your custom validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using `transform()` stated in the comments, as an alternative, you can use the `test` method. It might feel easier to use.

[Documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema)